# Ruby Sketchup ... exit

Tags: ruby, sketchup

The following script is executed within Sketchup as a ruby script.

```
notepad = File.absolute_path("notepad.exe", "C:/Windows")
puts "fileName :"+notepad
exec((notepad))
```

When closing the notepad.exe windows ... it also close/quit Sketchup.
How to only close notepad.exe and not Sketchup ?

Thks

Answer (score 2):

You are using `exec` to run notepad, but according to [documentation `exec`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-exec)  **replaces** the current process.
Try running the command using [`system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system) method instead - it executes command in a subshell

Comment: I'll try that asap.
thks

Comment: yes, it did works for me
I can quit an external program (ie notepad.exe) without quiting SKU

Comment: @user1803095 nice! If it worked for you then please mark the answer as accepted so that people on stackoverflow will know the solution worked